# MySQL Stored Procedure Call With List

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Here's my problem, I've got a stored procedure (Limited_Access_Users) I need to call and pass through a list of ID's so that it goes into a variable which is used by the where clause's cl_no in (id_list).

I've tried below but haven't had any luck. Each time it only take the first parameter  "1" and not "20".

CALL Limited_Access_Users ('1,20')

CALL Limited_Access_Users ("1,20")

**Stored Procedure**

CREATE DEFINER=`IDPAdmin`@`%` PROCEDURE `Limited_Access_Users`(
IN id_list TEXT)
BEGIN

select DISTINCT c.c_no, cl_no, 1

FROM
contacts c
join contacts_notes cn on c.c_no = cn.c_no 
and (cn_status =1 or cn_status is null)
where cl_no in (id_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
drop procedure if exists doSomething1234$$

CREATE PROCEDURE doSomething1234
(IN id_list TEXT)
BEGIN
    -- note id_list is passed in like a string '1,2,3,7'
    -- it will be wrapped for the in clause like in (1,2,3,7)
    --
    -- select DISTINCT c.c_no, cl_no, 1
    -- FROM contacts c join contacts_notes cn 
    -- on c.c_no = cn.c_no and (cn_status =1 or cn_status is null) 
    -- where cl_no in (id_list)

    set @sql1='select DISTINCT c.c_no, cl_no, 1 FROM contacts c join contacts_notes cn';
    set @sql2=' on c.c_no = cn.c_no and (cn_status =1 or cn_status is null)';
    set @sql3=concat(' where cl_no in (',id_list,')');
    set @statement=concat(@sql1,@sql2,@sql3);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: At what point do I have to provide the original list of id's then? Sorry, if it's over kill to explain. I'm just trying to understand how to separate the varchar i'm passing through into a list.

Comment: basically the way you were, as `CALL Limited_Access_Users ('1,20')`

Comment: you can jam your id's in a worktable and not pass as comma separated list. i will show you a way any way you want to do it

Comment: THANK YOU! I've never used a prepared statement and this thing is awesome! I really appreciate your help @DrewPierce.

Comment: anytime chase, plenty of people here to help

Answer (score 0):

Since id_list is a string, you are basically saying `WHERE cl_no IN ("1,20")` not `WHERE cl_no IN (1, 20)`. You can get around this by constructing the query for a `PREPARE`d statement in the stored procedure.

Like so:

```
SET @Q := CONCAT("[first part of query]", the_list, "[the rest of the query]");
PREPARE thePS FROM @Q;
EXECUTE thePS;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE thePS;
```

*Warnings about SQL injection are applicable depending on accessibility of the Stored Procedure.*

*You'll probably want to use a session variable name more unique than @Q, in case code calling the stored procedure happens to rely on identifier.*

Comment: Got it! How would I create the prepared statement? I'd need it to be scalable depending on how many values are entered 1, 2, 5, 20.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html You'll see that you could construct the query as a parameterized one, but then you'd need to parse the list, and manually construct the parameter list to have the correct number of parameters anyway.